# quoting unquoted members in nested list

Tags: r, list, r-factor, quoting

Using  R, I generate a list that contains certain unquoted elements. Please see at the bottom- it is invalid javascript code.

**R code (does not work)**

```
outq <- lapply (out, function (el){
 el <- if( is.factor(el$ann) ){ 
 el$ann <- apply(el$ann, 1, function(e){ e <- paste('"', e, '"', sep="") })
 }   
})
```

In the R language, How can I quote the members of the `list$x$ann` factor?

When I try to parse this JSON, json2.js fails.

**Sample Data (Invalid JSON)**

```
results = JSON.parse(
{
 "result": {
 "tot": {
 "molal": [ 0.00071243, 0.00071243,      4,      4 ],
   "ann": [ , , ,  ] 
},
   "desc": {
 "val": [ 8.3486,      4, 0.8531, 4.0025, 0.99999, 0.00072541, 0.00071243,    100, -1.2983e-05, -0.00016223,     17, 111.02, 55.511 ],
   "ann": [ Charge balance, Adjusted to redox eq, , , , , , , , , , ,  ] 
},
   "species": {
 "molal": [ 55.508, 0.00029101, 2.3071e-09, 0.00042017, 0.00028731, 4.4532e-06, 4.9292e-07, 0.00069149, 1.0274e-05, 6.2142e-06, 4.9139e-12,      4,      0, 4.1166e-27,      4, 8.5144e-21 ],
   "act": [ 0.8531, 0.00010921, 4.4812e-09, 1.4857e-06, 7.7889e-05, 4.4532e-06, 9.6777e-07, 0.00024834, 3.3916e-06, 0.00028204, 4.9139e-12, 2.2702,      0, 4.1166e-27, 3.7925, 1.8453e-20 ] 
},
   "master": {
 "molal": [ 0.00071243, 0.00071243,      4, 8.2332e-27,      4, 1.7029e-20 ] 
},
   "pphases": {
 "moles": 9.9993,
   "delta": -0.00071243 
},
   "ListInfo": {
 "n": 1,
   "format": true 
} 
} 
}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you cannot use the RJSON / RJSONIO packages for R ?

Comment: I *am* using RJSONIO, but it does not quote the factor(s).

Comment: Well, you didn't say, or I overlooked it.  Factors are an R construct, so you may have to convert via `as.character()`.

Comment: since version 0.3.1, library RJSONIO also quotes the JSON representation of factor variables.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Good to know it now deals with factors properly.

Answer (score -2):

I have advanced a step forward  using this R code:

```
outq <- lapply (out, function (el){el <- if( is.factor(el$ann) ){ el$ann <- lapply(el$ann, function(e){   e <- paste('"', e, '"', sep="") })} else {el}})
```

Comment: but I'm still wondering: is there a more elegant way to quote strings (or coerce & quote any data type) in R?  is there a  recommended way ? or some library?

Comment: As Dirk said : el$ann <- as.character(el$ann) and then you can proceed normally.